My design variables have no impact on the constraints and objective function in OpenMDAO
So I am working on an optimization problem with OpenMDAO. The subject of the optimization problem is to find the best Volume regarding some mission requirements that you chose and then make the Volume converge using 2 ways to compute the weight and compute the delta. So in the end my problem is after doing the code, I run it and then I got an error message saying that : "DerivativesWarning:Constraints or objectives [('obj.obj', inds=[0]), ('c1.c1', inds=[0]), ('c2.c2', inds=[0])] cannot be impacted
by the design variables of the problem." and "DerivativesWarning:Design variables [('V', inds=[0]), ('FR', inds=[0])] have no impact on the constraints or objective."
So in my code there is 3 subclass that compute the 2 weight and 1 about aerodynamics values. Then in my optimization class I put my 3 subsystem, I connect my inputs and outputs and then create my objective function and constraints and finally I make the problem work by implementing the optimization and then I try to run it and have my error message
So here is the code (it has a lot of formulas but I think that is not really important in my subject I think ):
import openmdao.api as om
from math import *

AR_tails = 1.0
pho_cruise_alt = 0.00211 #in slug/ft3 4000ft
pho_max_alt = 0.001876 #in slug/ft3 8000ft
pho_sea_level = 0.002377 #in slug/ft3
Vs = 84.5 #en f/s
mu = 3.66*10**(-7) #in poise
tc = 0.15 #no unit
nb_lobes = 3 #no unit a voir si on veut mettre ca dasn l'optimisation
range = 1000 #in nautical miles 
NE = 4 #number of engine, no unit, a voir par la suite avec la reliaility
BR = 0.7 #no unit
BSFC = 0.48 #Brake Specific fuel consumption, no unit
Payload = 40000 #in lb
FS = 4 #Security factor, no unit
Manufacturing_factor = 1.2 #no unit
nb_septum = 2 #no unit,a voir si je modifie ca pour permettre de le modif 
Faf = 1.26 #account for the external attach fitting, no unit
Seaming_factor = 1.06 #no unit
nb_ball = nb_lobes*2 #6 #no unit
Fpsq = 1.0 #account for the fabrication of the tail in lightweight structural material, no unit
surface_CS = 0.2 #percentage of the CS on the tail surface, no unit
Fact = 0.79 #no unit
Finstall = 1.15 #account for the installation of actuators, no unit
lec = 150 #account for the length of control cable for the engines, in ft
Nb_prop = 4 #no unit
Nbl = 3 #no unit
Kp = 31.92 #no unit
nt = 2 #number of fuel tank, no unit
Integral_tank = 0 #percentage of fuel tank that are integral, no unit
Npad = 3 #number of pads for ACLS, no unit
Vsr = 4 #landing sink rate, in f/s
Wcomputer = 250 #account for the weight of the computer, it's estimated, in lb
Wavionics = 250 #account for the weight of instruments, in lb
Wfs = 470 #account for the weight of fuel system, in lb
Kelect = 33.73 #account for a coef that depend on the type of range flight, no unit
np = 0.65 #propeller efficiency, no unit


class Geometry(om.ExplicitComponent):
    def setup(self):
        self.add_input('V',val=1000000.0)
        self.add_input('FR',val=3.0)
        self.add_output('V23',val=1.0)
        self.add_output('de',val=3.0)
        self.add_output('lb',val=1.0)
        self.add_output('dc',val=1.0)
        self.add_output('w',val=1.0)
        self.add_output('ht',val=1.0)
        self.add_output('AR',val=1.0)
        self.add_output('Swet_body_lobed',val=1.0)
        self.add_output('SHT',val=1.0)
        self.add_output('SVT',val=1.0)
        self.add_output('Wg',val=1.0)
        self.add_output('Wh0',val=1.0)
        self.add_output('Wh1',val=1.0)
        self.add_output('total_fuel',val=1.0)
        self.add_output('Woe',val=1.0)
        self.add_output('Cd0',val=1.0)
        self.add_output('K',val=1.0)

    def setup_partials(self):
        # Finite difference all partials.
        self.declare_partials('*', '*', method='fd')

    def compute(self,inputs,outputs):
        V = inputs['V']
        FR = inputs['FR']
        V23 = outputs['V23']
        de = outputs['de']
        lb = outputs['lb']
        dc = outputs['dc']
        w = outputs['w']
        ht = outputs['ht']
        AR = outputs['AR']
        Swet_body_lobed = outputs['Swet_body_lobed']
        SHT = outputs['SHT']
        SVT = outputs['SVT']
        Wg= outputs['Wg']
        Wh0=outputs['Wh0']
        Wh1=outputs['Wh1']
        total_fuel=outputs['total_fuel']
        Woe = outputs['Woe']
        Cd0 = outputs['Cd0']
        K = outputs['K']

        V23 = (float(V))**(2/3)
        de = ((6*V)/(FR*pi))**(1/3) #equivalent diameter of body of revolution
        lb = FR*de
        dc = (de/(-0.0178*nb_lobes**2+0.361*nb_lobes+0.575))
        w = (1+nb_lobes)*(dc/2)
        ht = dc
        AR = ((4*w**2)/(pi*lb*w))
        p = 1.6075
        Swet_body_ellipsoid = pi*((lb**p*w**p+lb**p*ht**p+w**p*ht**p)/3)**(1/p)
        if nb_lobes == 1:
            p_ellipsoid = 2*pi*(dc/2)
            p_lobes = 2*pi*(dc/2)
        if nb_lobes == 2:
            p_ellipsoid = 2.525*pi*(dc/2)
            p_lobes = (8*pi*(dc/2))/3
        if nb_lobes == 3:
            p_ellipsoid = 3.084*pi*(dc/2)
            p_lobes = (10*pi*(dc/2))/3
        if nb_lobes == 4:
            p_ellipsoid = 3.663*pi*(dc/2)
            p_lobes = (12*pi*(dc/2))/3
        if nb_lobes == 5:
            p_ellipsoid = 4.254*pi*(dc/2)
            p_lobes = (14*pi*(dc/2))/3
        Swet_body_lobed = (p_lobes/p_ellipsoid)*Swet_body_ellipsoid
        CHT = -0.0051*(1000000/V)+0.0717
        SHT = CHT*(V23*lb)/(0.38*lb)
        CVT = -0.0049*(1000000/V)+0.0641
        SVT = CVT*(V23*lb)/(0.38*lb)
        Cd0tab = []
        q = (1/2)*pho_cruise_alt*Vs**2
        Re = ((lb*Vs*pho_cruise_alt)/mu)
        Cf = (0.455/(log10(Re)**2.58))
        FF3D_body = 1+(1.5/FR**1.5)+(7/FR**3)
        Cd0_body = ((FF3D_body*Cf*Swet_body_lobed)/V23)
        Cd0tab.append(Cd0_body)
        FF_tail = 1+1.2*tc+100*tc**4
        ctail = ((AR_tails*SHT*0.5)**0.5+(AR_tails*SVT*0.5)**0.5)/2
        Re_tail = (ctail*Vs*pho_cruise_alt)/mu
        cf_tail = 0.455/(log10(Re_tail)**2.58)
        Swet_tail = 2.2*(SHT+SVT)
        Cd0_tail = (FF_tail*cf_tail*Swet_tail)/V23
        Cd0tab.append(Cd0_tail)
        #Add every Cd0 for each part of the airship, check what we choose in the end 
        Cd0cab = (0.108*Cd0_body*V23+7.7)/V23
        Cd0tab.append(Cd0cab)
        Cd0eng = NE*4.25/V23
        Cd0tab.append(Cd0eng)
        Cd0engcooling = NE*(2*10**(-6)*V+4.1)/V23
        Cd0tab.append(Cd0engcooling)
        Cd0engmount = (0.044*Cd0_body*V23+0.92)/V23
        Cd0tab.append(Cd0engmount)
        Cd0cables = (9.7*10**(-6)*V+10.22)/V23
        Cd0tab.append(Cd0cables)
        Cd0ACLS = 0.0002
        Cd0tab.append(Cd0ACLS)
        Cd0_int = (4.78*10**(-6)*V)/V23
        Cd0tab.append(Cd0_int)
        Cd0 = sum(Cd0tab)
        K = -0.0145*(1/AR)**4 + 0.182*(1/AR)**3 - 0.514*(1/AR)**2 + 0.838*(1/AR) - 0.053
        if nb_lobes == 1:
            Nl = 2
        if nb_lobes == 2:
            Nl = 2.25
        if nb_lobes == 3:
            Nl = 2.4
        if nb_lobes == 4:
            Nl = 2.5
        if nb_lobes == 5:
            Nl = 2.54
        K = K/Nl
        L = 0.0646*V*(pho_max_alt/pho_sea_level)
        Wlanding = L/BR
        Wh1 = Wlanding - L
        A = (326*np)/(BSFC*sqrt(K*Cd0))
        B = q*V23*sqrt(Cd0/K)
        Wh0 = B*tan((range/A)+atan(Wh1/B))
        fuel_burned = Wh0-Wh1
        fuelres = fuel_burned*0.05
        total_fuel = fuel_burned+fuelres
        Wzf = (L/BR)-fuelres
        Woe = Wzf - Payload
        Wg = Wlanding + fuel_burned
       

class aerodynamic(om.ExplicitComponent):
    def setup(self):
        self.add_input('Wh0',val=1.0)
        self.add_input('V23',val=1.0)
        self.add_input('Cd0',val=1.0)
        self.add_input('K',val=1.0)
        self.add_output('qmax',val=1.0)
        self.add_output('Maxpower_perengine',val=1.0)
        self.add_output('Dp',val=1.0)
        self.add_output('np_check',val=1.0)

    def setup_partials(self):
        self.declare_partials('*','*',method='fd')

    def compute(self,inputs,outputs):   
        Wh0= inputs['Wh0']
        V23= inputs['V23']
        Cd0= inputs['Cd0']
        K= inputs['K']
        qmax= outputs['qmax']
        Maxpower_perengine= outputs['Maxpower_perengine']
        Dp= outputs['Dp']
        np_check= outputs['np_check']


        L_aero = Wh0
        qmax = pho_sea_level*(((Vs*1.1)**2)/2)
        Clmax_power = (L_aero/qmax/V23)
        Drag = (Cd0+K*Clmax_power**2)*qmax*V23
        Maxpower_perengine = (Vs*1.1)*(Drag/np/NE/550)
        Cs = ((pho_sea_level*Vs**5)/Maxpower_perengine/550/10**2)**(1/5) #10 correspond a une rotation max pour le propeller speed and pho is in slug/ft3
        J = 0.156*Cs**2+0.241*Cs+0.138
        Dp = ((Vs)/10)/J
        np_check = 0.139*Cs**3-0.749*Cs**2+1.37*Cs+0.0115

class second_weight_estimation(om.ExplicitComponent):
    def setup(self):
        self.add_input('qmax',val=1.0)
        self.add_input('ht',val=1.0)
        self.add_input('V',val=1000000.0)
        self.add_input('SHT',val=1.0)
        self.add_input('SVT',val=1.0)
        self.add_input('Swet_body_lobed',val=1.0)
        self.add_input('dc',val=1.0)
        self.add_input('lb',val=1.0)
        self.add_input('Maxpower_perengine',val=1.0)
        self.add_input('Dp',val=1.0)
        self.add_input('total_fuel',val=1.0)
        self.add_input('Woe',val=1.0)
        self.add_input('Wh0',val=1.0)
        self.add_input('Wh1',val=1.0)
        self.add_output('Wg2',val=1.0)

    def setup_partials(self):
        self.declare_partials('*','*',method='fd')

    def compute(self,inputs,outputs):
        qmax = inputs['qmax']
        ht = inputs['ht']
        V = inputs['V']
        SHT = inputs['SHT']
        SVT = inputs['SVT']
        Swet_body_lobed = inputs['Swet_body_lobed']
        dc = inputs['dc']
        lb = inputs['lb']
        Maxpower_perengine = inputs['Maxpower_perengine']
        Dp = inputs['Dp']
        total_fuel = inputs['total_fuel']
        Woe = inputs['Woe']
        Wh0 = inputs['Wh0']
        Wh1 = inputs['Wh1']
        Wg2 = outputs['Wg2']



        Weight = []
        Pint = 1.2*qmax+0.0635*ht
        hull_fabric_load = FS*12*(Pint/144)*(dc/2)
        hull_fabric_density = 0.0085*hull_fabric_load+1.365
        Whull = hull_fabric_density*Manufacturing_factor*Faf*Swet_body_lobed/(16*9) #to convert each unit in yd2 and then go into lb
        Septum_fabric_load = 1.5*hull_fabric_load
        Septum_fabric_density = 0.0085*Septum_fabric_load+1.365
        side_body_area = 0.75 #percentage of envelope side body area 
        Wseptum = nb_septum*Seaming_factor*Septum_fabric_density*side_body_area*pi*ht*(lb/4)/(16*9) #we have a formula for the body side area after side body area
        Wenv = Wseptum+Whull
        Weight.append(Wenv)
        Vball = V*((1/(pho_max_alt/pho_sea_level))-1)
        Sball = nb_ball*pi*(nb_lobes*((Vball/pi)/6))**(2/3)
        Wball = 0.035*Sball
        Weight.append(Wball)
        Wssf = Fpsq*(SHT+SVT)*Faf*(1-surface_CS)
        Wcs = Fpsq*(SHT+SVT)*surface_CS
        Wtail = Wcs+Wssf
        Weight.append(Wtail)
        Wact = Fact*Finstall*surface_CS*(SHT+SVT)
        Weng = NE*Maxpower_perengine**(0.7956)*4.848
        Weight.append(Weng)
        Wengmt = 0.64*Weng
        Weight.append(Wengmt)
        Wec = 60.27*(lec*(NE/100))**(0.724)
        Weight.append(Wec)
        Wstart = 50.38*((Weng/1000))**(0.459)
        Weight.append(Wstart)
        Wprop = Nb_prop*Kp*Nbl**(0.391)*(Dp*(Maxpower_perengine/1000))**(0.782)
        Weight.append(Wprop)
        Wft = 2.49*(total_fuel/6)**(0.6)*nt**(0.2)*NE**(0.13)*(1/(1+Integral_tank))**(0.3) #total fuel is divided by 6 which the weight in lb per gallon for aviation gas
        Weight.append(Wft)
        Wpress_syst = 0.02*Woe
        Weight.append(Wpress_syst)
        Ppad = Pint
        ACLS_area_landing = 3*(0.23*Wh1*(Vsr/(Npad*Ppad))) #we multiply it by 3 because 3 pads but the configuration can change some stuff and then modify the calculations
        ACLS_area_takeoff = Wh0/Ppad
        Wacls = 1.6*max(ACLS_area_landing,ACLS_area_takeoff)
        Weight.append(Wacls)
        Wvms = Wcomputer+Wavionics+Wact
        Weight.append(Wvms)
        Welect = Kelect * (Wfs+Wcomputer+Wavionics)**(0.51)  #maybe don't have this equation 
        Weight.append(Welect)
        Wmsys = 0.05*Woe
        Weight.append(Wmsys)
        Wuf = 0.01*total_fuel
        Weight.append(Wuf)
        Wmargin = 0.06*Woe
        Weight.append(Wmargin)
        Woe2 = sum(Weight)
        Wg2 = Woe2 + total_fuel + Payload

class Optimization(om.Group):
    def setup(self):
        cycle = self.add_subsystem('cycle',om.Group(),promotes_inputs=['V','FR'])
        cycle.add_subsystem('d1', Geometry(),promotes_inputs=['V','FR'])
        cycle.add_subsystem('d4', aerodynamic())
        cycle.add_subsystem('d5', second_weight_estimation(),promotes_inputs=['V'])

        cycle.connect('d1.V23','d4.V23')
        cycle.connect('d1.lb','d5.lb')
        cycle.connect('d1.dc','d5.dc')
        cycle.connect('d1.ht','d5.ht')
        cycle.connect('d1.Swet_body_lobed','d5.Swet_body_lobed')
        cycle.connect('d1.SHT','d5.SHT')
        cycle.connect('d1.SVT','d5.SVT')
        cycle.connect('d1.Wh0','d4.Wh0')
        cycle.connect('d1.Wh0','d5.Wh0')
        cycle.connect('d1.Wh1','d5.Wh1')
        cycle.connect('d1.total_fuel','d5.total_fuel')
        cycle.connect('d1.Woe','d5.Woe')
        cycle.connect('d1.Cd0','d4.Cd0')
        cycle.connect('d1.K','d4.K')
        cycle.connect('d4.qmax','d5.qmax')
        cycle.connect('d4.Maxpower_perengine','d5.Maxpower_perengine')
        cycle.connect('d4.Dp','d5.Dp')


        cycle.nonlinear_solver = om.NonlinearBlockGS()

        cycle.set_input_defaults('V',val=2)

        self.add_subsystem('obj', om.ExecComp('obj = Wg - Wg2'), promotes= ['obj','Wg','Wg2'])
        self.add_subsystem('c1', om.ExecComp('c1 = L/Wg'), promotes=['c1','L','Wg'])
        self.add_subsystem('c2', om.ExecComp('c2 = np_check'), promotes=['c2','np_check'])


prob = om.Problem()
prob.model = Optimization()

prob.driver = om.ScipyOptimizeDriver()
prob.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'SLSQP'
# prob.driver.options['maxiter'] = 100
prob.driver.options['tol'] = 1e-8

prob.model.add_design_var('V', lower=0)
prob.model.add_design_var('FR', lower=0)
prob.model.add_objective('obj')
prob.model.add_constraint('c1', lower= 0, upper=0.6)
prob.model.add_constraint('c2', lower=0.95*np, upper=1.05*np)

# Ask OpenMDAO to finite-difference across the model to compute the gradients for the optimizer
prob.model.approx_totals()

prob.setup()
prob.set_val('V',2000000)
prob.set_val('FR',3)
prob.set_solver_print(level=0)

prob.run_driver()

print('minimum found at')
print(prob.get_val('V'))
print(prob.get_val('FR'))

print('minumum objective')
print(prob.get_val('obj'))

The total error message :
C:\Users\umroot\anaconda3\envs\fastuav\lib\site-packages\openmdao\core\total_jac.py:1626: DerivativesWarning:Constraints or objectives [('obj.obj', inds=[0]), ('c1.c1', inds=[0]), ('c2.c2', inds=[0])] cannot be impacted 
by the design variables of the problem.
C:\Users\umroot\anaconda3\envs\fastuav\lib\site-packages\openmdao\core\total_jac.py:1655: DerivativesWarning:Design variables [('V', inds=[0]), ('FR', inds=[0])] have no impact on the constraints or objective.
Positive directional derivative for linesearch    (Exit mode 8)
            Current function value: 0.0
            Iterations: 5
            Function evaluations: 1
            Gradient evaluations: 1
Optimization FAILED.
Positive directional derivative for linesearch
-----------------------------------
minimum found at
[2000000.]
[3.]
minumum objective
[0.]

Thanks in advance for looking at it and hope that we can find the solution together

it looks like you are doing some kind of aerodynamical optimization. Could you please provide more details about your case or maybe reference to a paper with approach description you are trying to implement in openmdao? I'm also working on aircraft optimization and at the moment digging into openmdao.

There are a few issues in the posted code.
When you write
np_check= outputs['np_check']

...

np_check = 5

Python does not write 5 into outputs['np_check'] as you might expect, but instead redefines it as a new integer. As a result, outputs['np_check'] maintains its default value (it's never overridden in the compute method).
To fix this, you can either assign to outputs['np_check'] directly, or force numpy to insert 5 into the array value of np_check using:
np_check[...] = 5

This explicitly tells numpy that you are shoving 5 into all elements of the np_check array (it only contains a single element in your instance).
After this, you'll still get an warning that the constraints and objectives cannot be impacted by your design variables.  The best thing to do in this situation is to open up the n-squared diagram that OpenMDAO automatically creates for you in reports/n2.html of the directory where you executed the script.

In this diagram, variables are listed on the left side. Any variable colored orange is not connected to an output elsewhere in the model.  For L and FR this makes sense because they are ultimately design variables provided by the optimizer.
But the diagram indicates that L, Wg, Wg2, and np_check are not connected to outputs. OpenMDAO is assuming that these inputs just hold whatever default value was assigned to them (typically 1.0), but the optimizer is not changing them.
These values appear to be outputs within the cycle group, but they need to be promoted, first out of their computing components, and then out of the cycle group itself.
            cycle = self.add_subsystem('cycle',om.Group(),
                                       promotes_inputs=['V','FR'],
                                       promotes_outputs=['Wg', 'Wg2', 'L', 'np_check'])
            cycle.add_subsystem('d1', Geometry(),
                                promotes_inputs=['V','FR'],
                                promotes_outputs=['Wg', 'L'])
            cycle.add_subsystem('d4', aerodynamic(),
                                promotes_outputs=['np_check'])
            cycle.add_subsystem('d5', second_weight_estimation(),
                                promotes_inputs=['V'],
                                promotes_outputs=['Wg2'])

FYI, I found this by clicking the "circled i" tool in the menubar on the left of the N2 diagram will allow you to see the "promoted" name of variables in the model.  Variables which share the same promoted name are implicitly connected in OpenMDAO.
Another thing I did was to remove the nonlinear solver assignment from the cycle group.  This group has no feedback, so the default nonlinear solver is preferred.
Finally, one of the constraints and the objective seemed to have values on the order of 1E6, so I scaled them by setting the ref value of those responses to 1.0E6.  This will cause the optimizer to see the value of 1.0E6 as 1.0.  There's a corresponding ref0 argument to add_objective and add_constraint that provides the value which the optimizer sees as zero.
With these changes, I get to a point where the optimizer is forcing the design into a region where log10(Re) is invalid.  You can try raising an OpenMDAO AnalysisError when this occurs, which will force some optimizers to walk back to a valid region, but in this case it seems to insist on driving to that region.
    import openmdao.api as om
    from math import *

    AR_tails = 1.0
    pho_cruise_alt = 0.00211 #in slug/ft3 4000ft
    pho_max_alt = 0.001876 #in slug/ft3 8000ft
    pho_sea_level = 0.002377 #in slug/ft3
    Vs = 84.5 #en f/s
    mu = 3.66*10**(-7) #in poise
    tc = 0.15 #no unit
    nb_lobes = 3 #no unit a voir si on veut mettre ca dasn l'optimisation
    range = 1000 #in nautical miles
    NE = 4 #number of engine, no unit, a voir par la suite avec la reliaility
    BR = 0.7 #no unit
    BSFC = 0.48 #Brake Specific fuel consumption, no unit
    Payload = 40000 #in lb
    FS = 4 #Security factor, no unit
    Manufacturing_factor = 1.2 #no unit
    nb_septum = 2 #no unit,a voir si je modifie ca pour permettre de le modif
    Faf = 1.26 #account for the external attach fitting, no unit
    Seaming_factor = 1.06 #no unit
    nb_ball = nb_lobes*2 #6 #no unit
    Fpsq = 1.0 #account for the fabrication of the tail in lightweight structural material, no unit
    surface_CS = 0.2 #percentage of the CS on the tail surface, no unit
    Fact = 0.79 #no unit
    Finstall = 1.15 #account for the installation of actuators, no unit
    lec = 150 #account for the length of control cable for the engines, in ft
    Nb_prop = 4 #no unit
    Nbl = 3 #no unit
    Kp = 31.92 #no unit
    nt = 2 #number of fuel tank, no unit
    Integral_tank = 0 #percentage of fuel tank that are integral, no unit
    Npad = 3 #number of pads for ACLS, no unit
    Vsr = 4 #landing sink rate, in f/s
    Wcomputer = 250 #account for the weight of the computer, it's estimated, in lb
    Wavionics = 250 #account for the weight of instruments, in lb
    Wfs = 470 #account for the weight of fuel system, in lb
    Kelect = 33.73 #account for a coef that depend on the type of range flight, no unit
    np = 0.65 #propeller efficiency, no unit


    class Geometry(om.ExplicitComponent):
        def setup(self):
            self.add_input('V',val=1000000.0)
            self.add_input('FR',val=3.0)
            self.add_output('V23',val=1.0)
            self.add_output('de',val=3.0)
            self.add_output('lb',val=1.0)
            self.add_output('dc',val=1.0)
            self.add_output('w',val=1.0)
            self.add_output('ht',val=1.0)
            self.add_output('AR',val=1.0)
            self.add_output('Swet_body_lobed',val=1.0)
            self.add_output('SHT',val=1.0)
            self.add_output('SVT',val=1.0)
            self.add_output('Wg',val=1.0)
            self.add_output('Wh0',val=1.0)
            self.add_output('Wh1',val=1.0)
            self.add_output('total_fuel',val=1.0)
            self.add_output('Woe',val=1.0)
            self.add_output('Cd0',val=1.0)
            self.add_output('K',val=1.0)
            self.add_output('L', val=1.0)

        def setup_partials(self):
            # Finite difference all partials.
            self.declare_partials('*', '*', method='fd')

        def compute(self,inputs,outputs):
            V = inputs['V']
            FR = inputs['FR']

            outputs['V23'] = V23 = V**(2/3)
            outputs['de'] = de = ((6*V)/(FR*pi))**(1/3) #equivalent diameter of body of revolution
            outputs['lb'] = lb = FR*de
            outputs['dc'] = dc = (de/(-0.0178*nb_lobes**2+0.361*nb_lobes+0.575))
            outputs['w'] = w = (1+nb_lobes)*(dc/2)
            outputs['ht'] = ht = dc
            outputs['AR'] = AR = ((4*w**2)/(pi*lb*w))
            p = 1.6075
            Swet_body_ellipsoid = pi*((lb**p*w**p+lb**p*ht**p+w**p*ht**p)/3)**(1/p)
            if nb_lobes == 1:
                p_ellipsoid = 2*pi*(dc/2)
                p_lobes = 2*pi*(dc/2)
            if nb_lobes == 2:
                p_ellipsoid = 2.525*pi*(dc/2)
                p_lobes = (8*pi*(dc/2))/3
            if nb_lobes == 3:
                p_ellipsoid = 3.084*pi*(dc/2)
                p_lobes = (10*pi*(dc/2))/3
            if nb_lobes == 4:
                p_ellipsoid = 3.663*pi*(dc/2)
                p_lobes = (12*pi*(dc/2))/3
            if nb_lobes == 5:
                p_ellipsoid = 4.254*pi*(dc/2)
                p_lobes = (14*pi*(dc/2))/3
            outputs['Swet_body_lobed'] = Swet_body_lobed = (p_lobes/p_ellipsoid)*Swet_body_ellipsoid
            CHT = -0.0051*(1000000/V)+0.0717
            outputs['SHT'] = SHT = CHT*(V23*lb)/(0.38*lb)
            CVT = -0.0049*(1000000/V)+0.0641
            outputs['SVT'] = SVT = CVT*(V23*lb)/(0.38*lb)
            Cd0tab = []
            q = (1/2)*pho_cruise_alt*Vs**2
            Re = ((lb*Vs*pho_cruise_alt)/mu)
            try:
                Cf = (0.455/(log10(Re)**2.58))
            except ValueError as e:
                raise om.AnalysisError('Re out of range')
            FF3D_body = 1+(1.5/FR**1.5)+(7/FR**3)
            Cd0_body = ((FF3D_body*Cf*Swet_body_lobed)/V23)
            Cd0tab.append(Cd0_body)
            FF_tail = 1+1.2*tc+100*tc**4
            ctail = ((AR_tails*SHT*0.5)**0.5+(AR_tails*SVT*0.5)**0.5)/2
            Re_tail = (ctail*Vs*pho_cruise_alt)/mu
            cf_tail = 0.455/(log10(Re_tail)**2.58)
            Swet_tail = 2.2*(SHT+SVT)
            Cd0_tail = (FF_tail*cf_tail*Swet_tail)/V23
            Cd0tab.append(Cd0_tail)
            #Add every Cd0 for each part of the airship, check what we choose in the end
            Cd0cab = (0.108*Cd0_body*V23+7.7)/V23
            Cd0tab.append(Cd0cab)
            Cd0eng = NE*4.25/V23
            Cd0tab.append(Cd0eng)
            Cd0engcooling = NE*(2*10**(-6)*V+4.1)/V23
            Cd0tab.append(Cd0engcooling)
            Cd0engmount = (0.044*Cd0_body*V23+0.92)/V23
            Cd0tab.append(Cd0engmount)
            Cd0cables = (9.7*10**(-6)*V+10.22)/V23
            Cd0tab.append(Cd0cables)
            Cd0ACLS = 0.0002
            Cd0tab.append(Cd0ACLS)
            Cd0_int = (4.78*10**(-6)*V)/V23
            Cd0tab.append(Cd0_int)
            outputs['Cd0'] = Cd0 = sum(Cd0tab)
            outputs['K'] = -0.0145*(1/AR)**4 + 0.182*(1/AR)**3 - 0.514*(1/AR)**2 + 0.838*(1/AR) - 0.053
            if nb_lobes == 1:
                Nl = 2
            if nb_lobes == 2:
                Nl = 2.25
            if nb_lobes == 3:
                Nl = 2.4
            if nb_lobes == 4:
                Nl = 2.5
            if nb_lobes == 5:
                Nl = 2.54
            outputs['K'] = K = outputs['K']/Nl
            outputs['L'] = L = 0.0646*V*(pho_max_alt/pho_sea_level)
            Wlanding = L/BR
            outputs['Wh1'] = Wh1 = Wlanding - L
            A = (326*np)/(BSFC*sqrt(K*Cd0))
            B = q*V23*sqrt(Cd0/K)
            outputs['Wh0'] = Wh0 = B*tan((range/A)+atan(Wh1/B))
            fuel_burned = Wh0-Wh1
            fuelres = fuel_burned*0.05
            outputs['total_fuel'] = fuel_burned+fuelres
            Wzf = (L/BR)-fuelres
            outputs['Woe'] = Wzf - Payload
            outputs['Wg'] = Wlanding + fuel_burned

    class aerodynamic(om.ExplicitComponent):
        def setup(self):
            self.add_input('Wh0',val=1.0)
            self.add_input('V23',val=1.0)
            self.add_input('Cd0',val=1.0)
            self.add_input('K',val=1.0)
            self.add_output('qmax',val=1.0)
            self.add_output('Maxpower_perengine',val=1.0)
            self.add_output('Dp',val=1.0)
            self.add_output('np_check',val=1.0)

        def setup_partials(self):
            self.declare_partials('*','*',method='fd')

        def compute(self,inputs,outputs):
            Wh0= inputs['Wh0']
            V23= inputs['V23']
            Cd0= inputs['Cd0']
            K= inputs['K']
            qmax = outputs['qmax']
            Maxpower_perengine = outputs['Maxpower_perengine']
            Dp= outputs['Dp']
            np_check= outputs['np_check']


            L_aero = Wh0
            qmax[...] = pho_sea_level*(((Vs*1.1)**2)/2)
            Clmax_power = (L_aero/qmax/V23)
            Drag = (Cd0+K*Clmax_power**2)*qmax*V23
            Maxpower_perengine[...] = (Vs*1.1)*(Drag/np/NE/550)
            Cs = ((pho_sea_level*Vs**5)/Maxpower_perengine/550/10**2)**(1/5) #10 correspond a une rotation max pour le propeller speed and pho is in slug/ft3
            J = 0.156*Cs**2+0.241*Cs+0.138
            Dp[...] = ((Vs)/10)/J
            np_check[...] = 0.139*Cs**3-0.749*Cs**2+1.37*Cs+0.0115

    class second_weight_estimation(om.ExplicitComponent):
        def setup(self):
            self.add_input('qmax',val=1.0)
            self.add_input('ht',val=1.0)
            self.add_input('V',val=1000000.0)
            self.add_input('SHT',val=1.0)
            self.add_input('SVT',val=1.0)
            self.add_input('Swet_body_lobed',val=1.0)
            self.add_input('dc',val=1.0)
            self.add_input('lb',val=1.0)
            self.add_input('Maxpower_perengine',val=1.0)
            self.add_input('Dp',val=1.0)
            self.add_input('total_fuel',val=1.0)
            self.add_input('Woe',val=1.0)
            self.add_input('Wh0',val=1.0)
            self.add_input('Wh1',val=1.0)
            self.add_output('Wg2',val=1.0)

        def setup_partials(self):
            self.declare_partials('*','*',method='fd')

        def compute(self,inputs,outputs):
            qmax = inputs['qmax']
            ht = inputs['ht']
            V = inputs['V']
            SHT = inputs['SHT']
            SVT = inputs['SVT']
            Swet_body_lobed = inputs['Swet_body_lobed']
            dc = inputs['dc']
            lb = inputs['lb']
            Maxpower_perengine = inputs['Maxpower_perengine']
            Dp = inputs['Dp']
            total_fuel = inputs['total_fuel']
            Woe = inputs['Woe']
            Wh0 = inputs['Wh0']
            Wh1 = inputs['Wh1']
            Wg2 = outputs['Wg2']

            Weight = []
            Pint = 1.2*qmax+0.0635*ht
            hull_fabric_load = FS*12*(Pint/144)*(dc/2)
            hull_fabric_density = 0.0085*hull_fabric_load+1.365
            Whull = hull_fabric_density*Manufacturing_factor*Faf*Swet_body_lobed/(16*9) #to convert each unit in yd2 and then go into lb
            Septum_fabric_load = 1.5*hull_fabric_load
            Septum_fabric_density = 0.0085*Septum_fabric_load+1.365
            side_body_area = 0.75 #percentage of envelope side body area
            Wseptum = nb_septum*Seaming_factor*Septum_fabric_density*side_body_area*pi*ht*(lb/4)/(16*9) #we have a formula for the body side area after side body area
            Wenv = Wseptum+Whull
            Weight.append(Wenv)
            Vball = V*((1/(pho_max_alt/pho_sea_level))-1)
            Sball = nb_ball*pi*(nb_lobes*((Vball/pi)/6))**(2/3)
            Wball = 0.035*Sball
            Weight.append(Wball)
            Wssf = Fpsq*(SHT+SVT)*Faf*(1-surface_CS)
            Wcs = Fpsq*(SHT+SVT)*surface_CS
            Wtail = Wcs+Wssf
            Weight.append(Wtail)
            Wact = Fact*Finstall*surface_CS*(SHT+SVT)
            Weng = NE*Maxpower_perengine**(0.7956)*4.848
            Weight.append(Weng)
            Wengmt = 0.64*Weng
            Weight.append(Wengmt)
            Wec = 60.27*(lec*(NE/100))**(0.724)
            Weight.append(Wec)
            Wstart = 50.38*((Weng/1000))**(0.459)
            Weight.append(Wstart)
            Wprop = Nb_prop*Kp*Nbl**(0.391)*(Dp*(Maxpower_perengine/1000))**(0.782)
            Weight.append(Wprop)
            Wft = 2.49*(total_fuel/6)**(0.6)*nt**(0.2)*NE**(0.13)*(1/(1+Integral_tank))**(0.3) #total fuel is divided by 6 which the weight in lb per gallon for aviation gas
            Weight.append(Wft)
            Wpress_syst = 0.02*Woe
            Weight.append(Wpress_syst)
            Ppad = Pint
            ACLS_area_landing = 3*(0.23*Wh1*(Vsr/(Npad*Ppad))) #we multiply it by 3 because 3 pads but the configuration can change some stuff and then modify the calculations
            ACLS_area_takeoff = Wh0/Ppad
            Wacls = 1.6*max(ACLS_area_landing,ACLS_area_takeoff)
            Weight.append(Wacls)
            Wvms = Wcomputer+Wavionics+Wact
            Weight.append(Wvms)
            Welect = Kelect * (Wfs+Wcomputer+Wavionics)**(0.51)  #maybe don't have this equation
            Weight.append(Welect)
            Wmsys = 0.05*Woe
            Weight.append(Wmsys)
            Wuf = 0.01*total_fuel
            Weight.append(Wuf)
            Wmargin = 0.06*Woe
            Weight.append(Wmargin)
            Woe2 = sum(Weight)
            Wg2[...] = Woe2 + total_fuel + Payload

    class Optimization(om.Group):
        def setup(self):
            cycle = self.add_subsystem('cycle',om.Group(),
                                       promotes_inputs=['V','FR'],
                                       promotes_outputs=['Wg', 'Wg2', 'L', 'np_check'])
            cycle.add_subsystem('d1', Geometry(),
                                promotes_inputs=['V','FR'],
                                promotes_outputs=['Wg', 'L'])
            cycle.add_subsystem('d4', aerodynamic(),
                                promotes_outputs=['np_check'])
            cycle.add_subsystem('d5', second_weight_estimation(),
                                promotes_inputs=['V'],
                                promotes_outputs=['Wg2'])

            cycle.connect('d1.V23','d4.V23')
            cycle.connect('d1.lb','d5.lb')
            cycle.connect('d1.dc','d5.dc')
            cycle.connect('d1.ht','d5.ht')
            cycle.connect('d1.Swet_body_lobed','d5.Swet_body_lobed')
            cycle.connect('d1.SHT','d5.SHT')
            cycle.connect('d1.SVT','d5.SVT')
            cycle.connect('d1.Wh0','d4.Wh0')
            cycle.connect('d1.Wh0','d5.Wh0')
            cycle.connect('d1.Wh1','d5.Wh1')
            cycle.connect('d1.total_fuel','d5.total_fuel')
            cycle.connect('d1.Woe','d5.Woe')
            cycle.connect('d1.Cd0','d4.Cd0')
            cycle.connect('d1.K','d4.K')
            cycle.connect('d4.qmax','d5.qmax')
            cycle.connect('d4.Maxpower_perengine','d5.Maxpower_perengine')
            cycle.connect('d4.Dp','d5.Dp')

            # No feedback, not necessary
            # cycle.nonlinear_solver = om.NonlinearBlockGS()

            cycle.set_input_defaults('V',val=2)

            self.add_subsystem('obj', om.ExecComp('obj = Wg - Wg2'), promotes= ['obj','Wg','Wg2'])
            self.add_subsystem('c1', om.ExecComp('c1 = L/Wg'), promotes=['c1','L','Wg'])
            self.add_subsystem('c2', om.ExecComp('c2 = np_check'), promotes=['c2','np_check'])


    prob = om.Problem()
    prob.model = Optimization()

    prob.driver = om.ScipyOptimizeDriver()
    prob.driver.options['maxiter'] = 100
    prob.driver.options['tol'] = 1e-8

    prob.model.add_design_var('V', lower=0, ref=1.0E6)
    prob.model.add_design_var('FR', lower=0)
    prob.model.add_objective('obj', ref=1.0E6)
    prob.model.add_constraint('c1', lower=0, upper=1.0)
    prob.model.add_constraint('np_check', lower=0.95*np, upper=1.05*np)

    # Ask OpenMDAO to finite-difference across the model to compute the gradients for the optimizer
    prob.model.approx_totals()

    prob.setup()
    prob.set_val('V',2000000)
    prob.set_val('FR',3)

    prob.run_driver()

At this point I think the structure of the OpenMDAO problem is OK (things appear to be connected properly), but something about the optimization problem is not working correctly because of the Reynolds number issue.

Thank you very much, I had time to go over every point and now it seems a little bit clearer on how to run an openMDAO optimization problem. I will now try to go over the issue of the Reynolds number but I don't quite get how can the log10(Re) can be invalid but I will check this
Thanks again for your answer !

Also I have a question, when I try to run it I see some warning that is RuntimeWarning does it affect the run of the problem or does it just inform us that at some point of the optimization it couldn't that calculation so it stopped going into this direction ?

Warnings are generally meant to let you know you might have a problem but not necessarily going to prevent it from working.

also another question, as I was trying to make the solver goes, I try to remove the ref=1.0E6 and then the code went crashing again saying math domain error, why if i remove this value it can't be solved ? Also I solved the other problem of Re by just putting a minimum value for the Volume that caused Re to be equal to 0

If you putref=1.0E6 on a design variable, objective, or constraint, it tells the optimizer to treat that value as 1.0.  Generally speaking, it divides the nominal value by ref to get the value that the optimizer sees. In this case, without that scaling, the optimizer ventures into a range where some calculation is invalid (maybe a negative Reynolds number, maybe something else).  It depends where you're seeing this behavior.

Also, parameterization in optimization is important.  If your model is such that plugging in certain input values can cause it to blow up, it might be worth while to think about how you can reformulate it in terms of inputs and outputs to avoid such trouble.
For instance, you could input the Reynolds number that is used in those calculations as a design variable, and then have a corresponding constraint that the given Reynolds number equals the computed one.  That way the analysis is always successful, although not always physically valid until the optimizer is satisfying all constraints.

Ok thanks, so if I understand correctly I could put the Re as a design variable and it could allow me to not put ref=1.0E6 in my objective function ? Also, I have a question is that normal that the convergence model I try to adapt into an openMDAO problem always give me a different solution like how can that be possible ?
